# sparseVector error involving checkSort and is.unsorted(i) in R

Tags: c#, r, dplyr, seurat

I'm trying to run the sparseVector() function on a fairly large vector in a list. I extracted the nonzero counts into a separate vector so I can use it in the function.

```
# dataset[[2]] is the 29634 element vector I want to make into a sparse vector
nonzero_vector <- which(dataset[[2]] != 0)
```

However, when I try to run the sparseVector() function, I get an error that I cannot find anywhere on the Internet and seems to be quite rare.

```
sparseVector(dataset[[2]], nonzero_vector, 29634)
Error in if (checkSort && is.unsorted(i)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what this error is and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the package name for the sparseVector function (e.g. library(Matrix)). Another helpful tip would be to provide a small reproducible example. Can you generate a short example vector and show that your code produces the same error? This will allow others to play with your code to get things working.